# How can I make a plugin for Vscode to change colors of a file type?

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

for example `.xlp` is my file type and name is `code.xlp` I want to highlight some code.

or some colors ?

Somethings like this
[Inno Setup For VS code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=idleberg.innosetup)

Comment: write an extension that contributes a language and write a textMate grammer file to specify which part of the file have which syntax highlight class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you don't want to write custom extension, try manual configuration of 'file association' for '.xlp' files.
This will tell VS Code to highlight content of '.xlp' files as language of your choice.

For example, I set it to C# and it looks like this:
[image]

Steps for this configuration:

1. Inside of '.xlp' file press `ctrl + P` to open navigation field,
2. Search for `>Change Language Mode`,
3. Choose *Configure File Association for '.xlp'*,
4. From dropdown list choose language you like.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned inside a comment you must write an `extension` for VS-Code to have your custom syntax highlighting for those files.

There is a good documentation available at:
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide

*At the mentioned web page you will find also more information about how to write your own extension and how to deploy it etc.*